# How to set a time zone for ESXi VM?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, timezone

I have several VMs that are heavily dependent on local time to start some services, and I want them to instantly have exact time at the moment of them starting. The issue is, there are both Windows and Linux VMs, and while Windows VMs can take local time from server unaltered, as Windows assumes that RTC has localized time, Linux VMs need to wait for NTP synchronization before, as Linux (at least CentOS and Debian) assumes that RTC stores UTC time. So I need to specify a setting for some VMs to have their starting RTC values adjusted to UTC time zone, in order for them to operate properly from the very start. How should I do this? NTP is in place but the issue occurs before NTP time adjustment triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Install vmtools inside all VMs then enable the 'Synchronize guest time with host ' option in each VM's settings, then make sure the ESXi host has the right time of course.

Oh and you can set this time setting in any VM templates you have too so that it's set on new VMs from those templates.

Comment: Hmm should not act as soon as I expect, but will check.